# Выборка по дате из БД по типу VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане. Изначально в работе с проектом не подразумевалась мысль о том что с датой придётся работать. Но на всякий случай она фиксировалась. С типом данных я не заморачивался и для простоты удобства указал `varchar`. Дата пишется следующим образом `18.06` без года. Время шло, детё выросло) И теперь мне необходимо вытащить некоторые данные из БД по дате и желательно в этом же самом формате `%d.%m`. Возможно ли это с типом `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Конечно. Вам просто нужен индекс на это поле, чтобы структурировать данные (ну и как результат, чтобы выборка была быстрой)

Comment: Возможно. Но лучше сразу сделать правильно и сконвертировать тип в `DATETIME` или `DATE`

Comment: Советую вам всё же сделать тип даты. Будет нормально работать сортировка. А нужный формат можно получать в запросе через `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: @ArchDemon если честно я и сам понимаю всё это. Но просто дело в том что уже во многих местах дата такого формата разбита через `explode()`. Была мысль изменить тип, но переделывать всё это так не хочется)

Comment: Может можно как то изменить тип, но оставить дату именно в таком формате?

Answer (score 0):

К моему удивлению, выборка прекрасно работает и напрямую без переопределения типов. Например:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_select` WHERE `date` <= '18.06'
```

`Результат: 18.06, 17.06, 16.06...`

`С реверсом: 18.06, 19.06, 20.06...`

Но стоит ли на это надёжно надеяться?)

Comment: К сожалению, это не будет работать. Как пример, попробуйте выбрать диапазон 15.05 - 25.06. Так как сравнение идет по первым символам, то это сделать вашим запросом не удастся.

Comment: Сделал всё по человечески всё же. Через тип данных `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите менять тип данных и выполнять преобразование, то придется использовать костыль.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_select` WHERE 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('2019-',SUBSTRING(date, 4, 2), "-", SUBSTRING(date, 1, 2))) <= 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-06-18')
```

Что делать я не рекомендую.